# mysql 5.6 flushing all dirty pages on ib_logfile rotation creating checkpoint stall

Tags: innodb, mysql-5.6

Server version: 5.6.23-72.1-log Percona

I have been trying to track down why our mysql server is sharp checkpointing and it seems to correlate with rotating of the ib_logfile.

I inherited this Percona 5.6 mysql server and it was pausing for the sharp checkpoint / full dirty flush once a day with innodb_log_file_size of 1GB. I thought perhaps it was insufficient logfile size and bumped it up to 25GB. Now we just get the same behavior less frequently. It was a sort of mystery to me until I was able to verify it happened when the logfile switched.

Mysql 5.5 docs: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/innodb-checkpoints.html: "...when InnoDB starts to reuse a log file, it has to make sure that the database page images on disk contain the modifications logged in the log file that InnoDB is going to reuse. In other words, InnoDB must create a checkpoint and this often involves flushing of modified database pages to disk."

Mysql 5.6 docs omit this bit and say all it should do is fuzzy checkpointing in normal circumstances. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-checkpoints.html: "InnoDB implements a checkpoint mechanism known as fuzzy checkpointing. InnoDB flushes modified database pages from the buffer pool in small batches. There is no need to flush the buffer pool in one single batch, which would disrupt processing of user SQL statements during the checkpointing process."

Is there any way to minimize or get out of this behavior if it is unexpected?

```
| innodb_adaptive_flushing | ON |
| innodb_adaptive_flushing_lwm | 10 |
| innodb_buffer_pool_size | 46170898432 |
| innodb_change_buffer_max_size | 25 |
| innodb_change_buffering | inserts |
| innodb_checksum_algorithm | innodb |
| innodb_checksums | ON |
| innodb_cleaner_lsn_age_factor | high_checkpoint |
| innodb_doublewrite | ON |
| innodb_empty_free_list_algorithm | backoff |
| innodb_file_format | Barracuda |
| innodb_file_per_table | ON |
| innodb_flush_log_at_timeout | 1 |
| innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit | 1 |
| innodb_flush_method | O_DIRECT |
| innodb_flush_neighbors | 0 |
| innodb_flushing_avg_loops | 30 |
| innodb_force_load_corrupted | OFF |
| innodb_force_recovery | 0 |
| innodb_foreground_preflush | exponential_backoff |
| innodb_io_capacity | 3000 |
| innodb_io_capacity_max | 6000 |
| innodb_log_arch_dir | ./ |
| innodb_log_arch_expire_sec | 0 |
| innodb_log_archive | OFF |
| innodb_log_block_size | 512 |
| innodb_log_buffer_size | 8388608 |
| innodb_log_checksum_algorithm | innodb |
| innodb_log_compressed_pages | ON |
| innodb_log_file_size | 26843545600 |
| innodb_log_files_in_group | 2 |
| innodb_log_group_home_dir | ./ |
| innodb_lru_scan_depth | 2048 |
| innodb_max_changed_pages | 1000000 |
| innodb_max_dirty_pages_pct | 50 |
| innodb_max_dirty_pages_pct_lwm | 0 |
| innodb_max_purge_lag | 200 |
| innodb_max_purge_lag_delay | 0 |
| innodb_old_blocks_pct | 37 |
| innodb_old_blocks_time | 1000 |
| innodb_online_alter_log_max_size | 134217728 |
| innodb_open_files | 384 |
| innodb_page_size | 16384 |
| innodb_purge_batch_size | 20 |
| innodb_purge_threads | 1 |
| innodb_random_read_ahead | OFF |
| innodb_read_ahead_threshold | 56 |
| innodb_read_io_threads | 4 |
| innodb_read_only | OFF |
| innodb_rollback_on_timeout | OFF |
| innodb_rollback_segments | 128 |
| innodb_sched_priority_cleaner | 19 |
| innodb_sort_buffer_size | 1048576 |
| innodb_spin_wait_delay | 6 |
| innodb_sync_spin_loops | 30 |
| innodb_table_locks | ON |
| innodb_thread_concurrency | 0 |
| innodb_thread_sleep_delay | 10000 |
| innodb_use_global_flush_log_at_trx_commit | ON |
| innodb_use_native_aio | ON |
| innodb_use_sys_malloc | ON |
| innodb_version | 5.6.23-72.1 |
| innodb_write_io_threads | 8 |
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Patching from Percona MySQL 5.6.23 to 5.6.47 and enabling innodb_numa_interleave has fixed this problem.

Answer (score 0):

The sentence about requiring a checkpoint before the log file rotation/reuse may have been removed from documentation, but the logic hasn't changed in version 5.6 -- you cannot overwrite log records that belong to not-yet-persisted data, so you have to checkpoint still. The fact that it is happening in your environment indicates that flushing of dirty pages with fuzzy checkpoints is not aggressive enough for your workload.

I'd try raising the `innodb_adaptive_flushing_lwm` threshold and lowering `innodb_max_dirty_pages_pct` to make page cleaning more proactive.

There are more hints and links [in this article](https://www.xaprb.com/blog/2011/01/29/how-innodb-performs-a-checkpoint/)

Comment: The way the 5.5 documentation reads to me, is through normal cycling of innodb logfiles it creates a hard checkpoint when the log rotates.  I'm now tracking when the logfiles rotate to verify my theory and its definitely interesting behavior that I wouldnt expect.  ib_logfile0 had the same timestamp for 7 hours, then it updated to a new timestamp but is keeping that once updated timestamp as ib_logfile1 continues to show a new timestamp whenever my script checks (every 5 minutes).  Is this how the logfiles rotate?

Comment: do you have any rough starting points for innodb_adaptive_flushing_lwm and innodb_max_dirty_pages_pct_lwm?

Comment: Rough starting points would be where they are today in your environment, `innodb_adaptive_flushing_lwm  = 10`, `innodb_max_dirty_pages_pct = 50` (sorry, I meant `innodb_max_dirty_pages_pct`, not `innodb_max_dirty_pages_pct_lwm`).

Comment: Ok, I've attempted lowering innodb_max_dirty_pages_pct to 20 and increased innodb_adaptive_flushing_lwm to 50 to see how it might affect behavior.  Im still interested way the ib_logfiles seem to rotate irregularly...

Comment: How fast the log file fills in depends on the transaction volume, obviously.

Comment: I installed PMM and got a picture of my hourly log file usage at something around 250MB/hour.  My final theory is that with my large buffer pool (43GB) and large log files (50GB total) that adaptive checkpointing is not kicking in, and that the lsn_cleaner is sleeping and never triggered because of this, and thusly I am getting into conditions where when the buffer pool is comparing against the logfile there are old dirty blocks in the buffer pool that arent flushed ahead of rotation causing a sharp checkpoint. Im going to attempt lowering the log file size dramatically to 128MB to see..